# Using OGG/Vorbis, is there a way to continue to record to an existing audio file?

Tags: audio, python, busybox, ogg

I am using Vorbis/ogg to record audio (using `arecord` and then pipping to oggenc). I have downloaded oggvideotools, which gave me `oggCat`, which will let me join two previously recorded audio files into one file. But, my problem is this:

The device I am working on is known to have the "plug pulled", but it is recording while the power is on (swapping out batteries etc.). Once the device is powered back on, I need to continue to record to the previous file (automated recording).

Right now, I can use `arecord` to record two separate files, and then once the recording is done, I can oggCat the two, but that doesn't get me what I want 100%, I need to be able to continue recording where the first file got cut off.

I need python and busybox solutions.  Unfortunately, other solutions outside Python and Busybox are not available to me - furthermore, downloading additional packages/programs is also not available, I have `oggenc`, `arecord`, and `oggvideotools`.

Any advise on where to look? Can I somehow pipe `arecord` data from a temp file to `oggCat`? Like:

```
oggCat NewFile.ogg File1.ogg (arecord file2.ogg ...)
```

Where `(arecord file2.ogg ...)`is the file currently being recorded and simultaneously being appended to `Newfile.ogg`?

PS. The audio files will have the exact same parameters - i.e. same channels, rates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but consider using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).  This will take the standard output of one program and provide it to another program via a pipe.

```
oggCat NewFile.ogg File1.ogg <(arecord)
```

If I am correct this would append the new recording to audio.ogg.  The biggest problem I see is that arecord appears outputs to output a wav by default so you may need to encode it as an ogg.

Sorry, I don't have a mic to test it out.  But I answered anyway because I felt that this is the bit you were looking for and can figure the rest out yourself.

Comment: Busybox ash does not support this syntax, as far as I know.